# Solving for final velocity of a simple Newtonian system

Tags: integration

A friend Asked me this question, and I feel like I should be able to do it, but I keep getting the wrong answer and it's really bothering me. Please help:

A Van passes a car at a constant Speed $V_{van}=80mph $. After 4 seconds, the Car accelerates with constant acceleration. The Car reaches the van at distance = 50m from where the van first overtook the car. Solve for the velocity of the car at the moment it overtakes the van.

My Attempt:

$$d = 50m; V_{van}= 35.7632 m/s; $$
$$d=V_{van}t = a(t-4)^2$$
$$a=\frac {d}{(t-4)^2}$$
I did $(t-4)$ because the car started accelerating 4 seconds after the van overtook. 
Time runs from $t=-4$ to $t=d/V_{van}=1.398 s$
$$V_{final}=\int {a}\delta t=V+C$$
$$\int {\frac {d}{(t-4)^2}}\delta t= -[\frac {d}{(t-4)}]^{1.398}_{-4}=0.25$$
which really can't be right. I'm not sure where I messed up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming $a$ is supposed to be acceleration then where does the equation $d=at^2$ come from?

Comment: If you integrated correctly you'd get $d = v_it+\frac 12at^2$.  It's easy to derive so I encourage you to try.

Comment: The real problem I'm having with this question is that after $4$ seconds, the van has already moved further than $50$ meters from where it passed the car.  So this doesn't seem to be a well-posed question.

Comment: Im sorry, can you tell me what you integrated? Is my expression for acceleration correct? I'm not sure what you did specifically.

Comment: @JLui OK.  Here's the derivation: $a$ is a constant, but it's also equal to $\frac{dv}{dt}$.  So we integrate: $$\int_0^t a\,d\tau = \int_0^t \frac{dv}{d\tau}\,d\tau \\ LHS: \int_0^t a\,d\tau = \left.a\tau\right|_0^t = at \\ RHS: \int_0^t \frac{dv}{d\tau}\,d\tau = \left.v(\tau)\right|_0^t = v(t) - v(0) = v(t) - v_i$$  Then $v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$, so we can integrate again: $$\int_0^t a\tau\,d\tau = \int_0^t (\frac{dx}{d\tau}-v_i)\,d\tau \\ LHS: \frac{at^2}{2} \\ RHS: x(t)-x(0)-v_it = x(t)-x_i-v_it$$  Now let $t=t_f$ to get $$\frac{at_f^2}2 = \Delta x-v_it_f$$

Comment: He didn't give me the initial velocity of the car. Maybe it cancels out somewhere

Comment: Either way, as I said in my third comment, this problem isn't solvable because the van has already moved more than $50$ meters in the $4$ seconds *before* the car accelerates.

Comment: Thanks so much Bye_world. I really appreciate that you took the time to show me.

Comment: No problem. :-)